# Passing form data express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

**Edit 2**

I've tried the following.

routes

```
// competition form details
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.find(req.params.id, function(err, competition){
    res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
      users: competition
    });
  });
});

// competition form details post
router.post('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body, {upsert:true}, (err, competition) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error saving data:  ${err}`);
      return res.send('Error saving data');
    }

    res.redirect('/dashboard');
    console.log(req.body);
  });
});
```

input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="schoolName" placeholder="Enter school name" value="{{competition.schoolName}}"
```

Still no luck.

**Edit 1**

So I have tested your example `value="{{user.schoolName}}"` with `users: CompetitionForm` in the route, however I get the field value from the user registration and not the CompetitionForm.

Here's what I have

user model

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useMongoClient: true });
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pol-development', { useMongoClient: true });
}

var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connection has been established");
});

var CompetitionFormSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  schoolName: String,
  competitionDate: String,
  competitionTime: String,
  competitionVenue: String,
  competitionTotalOfStudents: Number,
  competitionTotalParticipated: Number,
  competitionTotalPersonnel: Number,
  competitionJudge1Name: String,
  competitionJudge1Telephone: String,
  competitionJudge1Email: String,
  competitionJudge2Name: String,
  competitionJudge2Telephone: String,
  competitionJudge2Email: String,
  competitionJudge3Name: String,
  competitionJudge3Telephone: String,
  competitionJudge3Email: String,

  // admin fields
  competitionRequiredPhotos: Boolean,
  competitionRequiredCertifications: Boolean
});

var CompetitionForm = module.exports = mongoose.model('CompetitionForm', CompetitionFormSchema);
```

route

```
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.find(req.params.id, function(err, CompetitionForm){
    res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
      users: CompetitionForm
    });
  });
});
```

and for the form

`<form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user.id}}" method="post">`

```
<label for="schoolName">School Name <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="schoolName" placeholder="Enter school name" value="{{user.schoolName}}" required>
```

**Original**

I have a competition form and a collection called `competitionforms`

[image]

I have the form working using the following routes

```
// competition form details
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.find(req.params.id, function(err, CompetitionForm){
    res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
      user_id: req.params.id
    });
  });
});

// competition form details post
router.post('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body, {upsert:true}, (err, competition) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error saving data:  ${err}`);
      return res.send('Error saving data');
    }

    res.redirect('/dashboard');
    console.log(req.body);
  });
});
```

Now I want to pass the form data so the user can see what they have entered should they go back to the form.

The form is using the users id

```
<form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user_id}}" method="post">
```

So I have tried the following

`{{competitionforms.user.schoolName}}`,
`{{competitionforms.users.schoolName}}`,
`{{users.competitionforms.schoolName}}` and 
`{{user.competitionforms.schoolName}}`

I'm not sure what other combination I can try here.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to give you specifics without knowing what your template looks like but that is probably for the better since it appears there is a general misunderstanding of how Express renders the form from the template.

A very simplistic explanation is `res.render` takes a template and replaces any instances of specially formatted text, such as `{{foo}}`, with the values specified by the variable object as the second argument. So if that variable object had a `foo` property, that value would be used.

### Example #1:

Template (template.hbs):

```
Hi {{name}}! Is {{favoriteColor}} your favorite color?
```

Express App:

```
res.render('template.hbs', { name: 'John', favoriteColor: 'green' });
```

Rendered Output:

```
Hi John! Is green your favorite color?
```

---

### Example #2:

The provided variable object can also include embedded objects too!

Template (template.hbs):

```
Hi {{name.first}}! Is {{favorites.color}} your favorite color?
```

Express App:

```
res.render('template.hbs', { name: { first: 'John' }, favorites: { color: 'green' }});
```

Rendered Output:

```
Hi John! Is green your favorite color?
```

---

Bringing it back to your example, assuming your template looks something like the following:

Template (dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs):

```
<form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user.id}}" method="post">
  <label>School: <input type="text" name="schoolName" value="{{user.schoolName}}" /></label>
```

Then the updated Express code would look like:

```js
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    CompetitionForm.find(req.params.id, function(err, competitionForm){
        res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
          pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
          user: competitionForm
        });
    });
});
```

This assumes your document object (`competitionForm`) has a property of `schoolName`.

For further reading on using Mustache templates in Express, checkout:

- http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html
- https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

---

### Edit:

Based on your Edit #2:

routes

```
// competition form details
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.find(req.params.id, function(err, competition) {
    res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
      users: competition
    });
  });
});
```

input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="schoolName" placeholder="Enter school name" value="{{users.schoolName}}"
```

The template object properties *must* match the variable object properties so they can be accessed: `{ pageTitle: '...', users: {...} }` ==> `users.schoolName`

Comment: @B.J.B You have a typo in your edited code that would prevent the code from working: the variable object specifies a property of `users` but your template uses `user`. They need to be the same property name for it to work.

Comment: That's not a typo

Comment: @B.J.B Check my edit. That _should_ work. If not, I would recommend taking some time to read through the mustache [documentation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).